# Есть ли слово "вшагнуть"?

Tags: окказионализмы

В литературной речи его не встречал, но вот правила, которое бы запретило употреблять такое слово, не вижу.

Есть ли в языке препятствия для слова "вшагнуть", хотя бы в качестве авторского? Если да, то какие?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Есть ли слово “вшагнуть”?

Встречается у ряда писателей.

Отмечено и в книге "Новое в русской лексике: словарные материалы" (1996):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]